# How to install Nodejs 10.24.1 and Npm 5.6.1 in Termux Android?

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, nvm, termux

I installed Nodejs-lts on termux. It installed the latest version **v16.18.1** and **npm v8.19.2**. I want to downgrade/install Nodejs **10.24.1** and **Npm 5.6.1**.

I actually cloned an open-source project from GitHub using git to run it locally. So, the project was developed with **npm v5.6.0** when I ran npm install, I got an error saying `"The package-lock.json file was created with an old version of npm"`.

Comment: This message sounds like a waning, not an error

Comment: How did you install the latest version?

Comment: It's simple, run this -- pkg install nodejs-lts
I also downgraded it using proot-distro debian. It's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,

1. [Install any proot-distro step-1 to step 3.1](https://coder.com/docs/code-server/latest/termux#install)
2. Then [Install NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating)

Updated:
Seems like [Coder website](https://coder.com/docs/code-server/latest/termux#install) has removed the 'Linux distro installation using proot-distro instructions' after reference here lol XD XD

Anyways, here's Termux wiki,

1. [Install any Linux distro using proot-distro](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/PRoot)